# Typescript new type from object keys already typed as an interface

Tags: typescript, types

I'm facing this situation:

```
interface ListField {
  code: number;
  message: string;
}

interface List {
  [key: string]: ListField;
}

export const allCodes: List = {
  FIRST: {
    code: 1,
    message: 'message 1',
  },
  SECOND: {
    code: 2,
    message: 'message 2',
  },
  THIRD: {
    code: 3,
    message: 'message 3',
  },
};
```

I need a new type with all keys from allCodes, like
type Ok = "FIRST" | "SECOND" | "THIRD"

My idea (not working):

```
export type ListType = keyof typeof allCodes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `allCodes` doesn't have a literal type, but just `List`, which is an *index signature*. So if you try to get its keys you will get just a `string`.

Let's remove the type and see what is the new type:

```
const allCodes = {
  FIRST: {
    code: 1,
    message: 'message 1',
  },
  SECOND: {
    code: 2,
    message: 'message 2',
  },
  THIRD: {
    code: 3,
    message: 'message 3',
  },
}

// type AllCodes = {
//   FIRST: {
//       code: number;
//       message: string;
//   };
//   SECOND: {
//       code: number;
//       message: string;
//   };
//   THIRD: {
//       code: number;
//       message: string;
//   };
// }
type AllCodes = typeof allCodes
```

Looks good, however, it's not type safe, since we removed the type, which can be fixed by using the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator:

```
const allCodes = {
  FIRST: {
    code: 1,
    message: 'message 1',
  },
  SECOND: {
    code: 2,
    message: 'message 2',
  },
  THIRD: {
    code: 3,
    message: 'message 3',
  },
} satisfies List

// "FIRST" | "SECOND" | "THIRD"
type ListType = keyof typeof allCodes;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gGLAgGwBNkBvAKGWQQHtCIAuZEAVwFsAjaAbguVYgwY4AcwbIsUUMJ4BfMmVCRYiFOiyleAbQDWEAJ6MJUgLqM1OPEVnyaIdXHz4AwrQHIAvBsrYAkgCUAZQAVRnJKSho6RgBGABpeSn5BETEAciShUWRo1PjKGTzkAIBRJwB5ADkAEVCEqldGACZCxIFMtIyU5Ebc3gLeIIAJfxqvcMixAGYWvjaUxnS5rMne-PiZcTgwTBg8DDRMMHkAemPkACJfQKDz5AAfC5Ly6tuH86GR87IwPQAHVUOQT+KE8uj01BgyB+-whyAczlcGC4QA)

---

### Update

The author is unable to use the *satisfies* operator and the alternative approach would be using some dummy function with [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to prevent the compiler from widening the type:

```
const createCodes = <const T extends List>(list: T) => list;

const allCodes = createCodes({
  FIRST: {
    code: 1,
    message: 'message 1',
  },
  SECOND: {
    code: 2,
    message: 'message 2',
  },
  THIRD: {
    code: 3,
    message: 'message 3',
  },
})

// "FIRST" | "SECOND" | "THIRD"
type ListType = keyof typeof allCodes;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gGLAgGwBNkBvAKGWQQHtCIAuZEAVwFsAjaAbguVYgwY4AcwbIsUUMJ4BfMmVCRYiFOiyleAbQDWEAJ6MJUgLqM1OPEVnyaIdQigQ4kAMK0ByALzIAPLfUAKsgQAB6QIIQYaJhgAHwAFPgxjAEAlF6xyElYPGT+YMhw+PhudFHeDk6u7hjx5JTYAJIASgDKAYz1lFTujACMADS8lPyCImIA5KNCosh9E0OUMovIrQCiLgDyAHIAIp3DPXSMAEwrIwIzk9PjyCcLvMu8AQASLfsa3UdiAMznfJdxowpoDZj8HkshjJUvIAPSw5AAIiabQCiOQAB8kestnt0VjEa93oiyGA9AAHVQxAIUlDeXR6agwZBkylMwrFUoCLhAA)

Comment: Your solution works perfectly but if I add any additional nullable property inside ListField I'll receive an error if I try to access that key, becasue satisfies operator doesnt carry over optional properties. This is why I was trying without using satisfies

Comment: Not sure if I understood, can you include some code for that?

Comment: @crivella you could also do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gGLAgGwBNkBvAKGWQQHtCIAuZEAVwFsAjaAbguVYgwY4AcwbIsUUMJ4BfMmVCRYiFOiyleAbQDWEAJ6MJUgLqM1OPEVnyaIdQigQ4kAMK0ByALzIAPLfUAKsgQAB6QIIQYaJhgAHwAFPgxjAEAlF6xyElYPGT+YMhw+PhudFHeDk6u7hjx5JTYAJIASgDKAYz1lFTujACMADS8lPyCImIA5KNCosh9E0OUMovIrQCiLgDyAHIAIp3DPXSMAEwrIwIzk9PjyCcLvMu8AQASLfsa3UdiAMznfJdxowpoDZj8HkshjJUvIAPSw5AAIiabQCiOQAB8kestnt0VjEa93oiyGA9AAHVQxAIUlDeXR6agwZBkylMwrFUoCLhAA)

Comment: your second solution is perfect for my case! Please add it ad second option in your answer so I'll mark question as solved